# Reach a number with a given array as choosing only big numbers among it

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel or Excel Macro, I am trying to figure out an alghorithm/formula to reach a number with using highest ones as possible but there are some limitations. Let me explain with an example;

1. Let's say I have 5 numbers in 5 cells (line by line) to use (2,5,10,20,50) and I need to reach 98.
2. In this example, I should only use 50 + 20 + 20 + 5 + 2 + 2. Even if I can't reach exact number (like reaching 98), it should be the results with minimum exceeds (like 99). It can't be lower than the target number.
3. I will copy these rows (as fetching their numbers in their first column) and paste to another sheet from the list. Please think these numbers to select rows, so I could find the appropriate rows as finding the right algorithm / formula for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

Put your data for example (2,5,10,20,50) into A1:A5 at the top of sheet1.
Put the below code into a vba code module, and run Algorithm.
I wrote the result into column C, but modify as needed.

```
Sub Algorithm()
Dim Tgt As Double, currVal As Double
Dim iRow As Integer, oRow As Integer 'input and output row
Dim ary, sortedAry 'input arrays
Dim aResult(1 To 100, 1 To 1) 'assuming result is less than 100 rows long

Tgt = 98 'Target number

ary = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'put data into an array
sortedAry = BubbleSort(ary, False) 'sort in descending order

iRow = 1
oRow = 1
currVal = 0
Do Until iRow > UBound(sortedAry)
  If currVal + sortedAry(iRow, 1) > Tgt Then
    iRow = iRow + 1 'goto next smallest number
  Else
    aResult(oRow, 1) = sortedAry(iRow, 1)
    currVal = currVal + sortedAry(iRow, 1)
    oRow = oRow + 1
  End If
Loop

'one more so it goes over Tgt
aResult(oRow, 1) = sortedAry(UBound(sortedAry), 1)

'put results back into spreadsheet
Sheet1.Range("C1").Resize(100, 1) = aResult
End Sub

Function BubbleSort(myArray As Variant, Optional Ascending = True)
'suitable to sort a small list that is in a 1 column array
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim Temp As Variant

If Ascending = True Then
  For i = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 1) - 1
      For j = i + 1 To UBound(myArray)
          If myArray(i, 1) > myArray(j, 1) Then
              Temp = myArray(j, 1)
              myArray(j, 1) = myArray(i, 1)
              myArray(i, 1) = Temp
          End If
      Next j
  Next i
Else
  For i = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 1) - 1
      For j = i + 1 To UBound(myArray)
          If myArray(i, 1) < myArray(j, 1) Then
              Temp = myArray(j, 1)
              myArray(j, 1) = myArray(i, 1)
              myArray(i, 1) = Temp
          End If
      Next j
  Next i
End If
BubbleSort = myArray
End Function
```